# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appear is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me , I am getting script error in browser console.  I upgrade jquery but still it is same . Error reads like....

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appear is not a function
    <anonymous> http://localhost/frontdesign/dropdown/js/script.js:38
    jQuery 13
        e
        t
        setTimeout handler*l/<
        c
        fireWith
        fire
        c
        fireWith
        ready
        B
        EventListener.handleEvent*
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
```

Line number 38 part of script is below

```
$('.skill-shortcode').appear(function() {
        $('.progress').each(function(){ 
            $('.progress-bar').css('width',  function(){ 
                return ($(this).attr('data-percentage')+'%')});
        });
```

and complete scritp is below

```
/* ----------------- Start JS Document ----------------- */

// Page Loader
// $(window).load(function () {
//     "use strict";    
//  $('#loader').fadeOut();
// });

$(window).on('load', function(){

    "use strict";    
    $('#loader').fadeOut();
});



jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";   
     console.log( 'working!' )
    ////    Hidder Header   
    var headerEle = function () {
        var $headerHeight = $('header').height();
        $('.hidden-header').css({ 'height' : $headerHeight  + "px" });
    };
    
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        headerEle();
    });
    
    $(window).resize(function () {
        headerEle();
    });
    
    
    /*---------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Progress Bar
    /*---------------------------------------------------*/    
    $('.skill-shortcode').appear(function() {
        $('.progress').each(function(){ 
            $('.progress-bar').css('width',  function(){ 
                return ($(this).attr('data-percentage')+'%')});
        });
    },{accY: -100});    
    
    
    /*--------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Counter
    /*--------------------------------------------------*/   
        
    $('.timer').countTo();
    $('.counter-item').appear(function() {
        $('.timer').countTo();
    },{
        accY: -100
    });    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Nice-Scroll
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $("html").niceScroll({
        scrollspeed: 100,
        mousescrollstep: 38,
        cursorwidth: 5,
        cursorborder: 0,
        cursorcolor: '#333',
        autohidemode: true,
        zindex: 999999999,
        horizrailenabled: false,
        cursorborderradius: 0,
    });
        
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Nav Menu & Search
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $(".nav > li:has(ul)").addClass("drop");
    $(".nav > li.drop > ul").addClass("dropdown");
    $(".nav > li.drop > ul.dropdown ul").addClass("sup-dropdown");
    
    $('.show-search').click(function() {
        $('.search-form').fadeIn(300);
        $('.search-form input').focus();
    });
    $('.search-form input').blur(function() {
        $('.search-form').fadeOut(300);
    });
                
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Back Top Link
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    var offset = 200;
    var duration = 500;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
            $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(400);
        } else {
            $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(400);
        }
    });
    $('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
        return false;
    })
        
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Sliders & Carousel
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    ////------- Touch Slider
    var time = 4.4,
        $progressBar,
        $bar,
        $elem,
        isPause,
        tick,
        percentTime;
    $('.touch-slider').each(function(){
        var owl = jQuery(this),
            sliderNav = $(this).attr('data-slider-navigation'),
            sliderPag = $(this).attr('data-slider-pagination'),
            sliderProgressBar = $(this).attr('data-slider-progress-bar');
            
        if ( sliderNav == 'false' || sliderNav == '0' ) {
            var returnSliderNav = false
        }else {
            var returnSliderNav = true
        }
        
        if ( sliderPag == 'true' || sliderPag == '1' ) {
            var returnSliderPag = true
        }else {
            var returnSliderPag = false
        }
        
        if ( sliderProgressBar == 'true' || sliderProgressBar == '1' ) {
            var returnSliderProgressBar = progressBar
            var returnAutoPlay = false
        }else {
            var returnSliderProgressBar = false
            var returnAutoPlay = true
        }
        
        owl.owlCarousel({
            navigation : returnSliderNav,
            pagination: returnSliderPag,
            slideSpeed : 400,
            paginationSpeed : 400,
            lazyLoad : true,
            singleItem: true,
            autoHeight : true,
            autoPlay: returnAutoPlay,
            stopOnHover: returnAutoPlay,
            transitionStyle : "fade",
            afterInit : returnSliderProgressBar,
            startDragging : pauseOnDragging
        });
        
    });

    function progressBar(elem){
        $elem = elem;
        buildProgressBar();
        start();
    }
    
    function buildProgressBar(){
        $progressBar = $("<div>",{
            id:"progressBar"
        });
        $bar = $("<div>",{
            id:"bar"
        });
        $progressBar.append($bar).prependTo($elem);
    }
    
    function pauseOnDragging(){
      isPause = true;
    }
    
    ////------- Projects Carousel
    $(".projects-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation : true,
        pagination: false,
        slideSpeed : 400,
        stopOnHover: true,
        autoPlay: 3000,
        items : 4,
        itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3],
        itemsTablet: [600,2],
        itemsMobile : [479, 1]
    });
    
    
    
    ////------- Testimonials Carousel
    $(".testimonials-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation : true,
        pagination: false,
        slideSpeed : 2500,
        stopOnHover: true,
        autoPlay: 3000,
        singleItem:true,
        autoHeight : true,
        transitionStyle : "fade"
    });
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ////------- Custom Carousel
    $('.custom-carousel').each(function(){
        var owl = jQuery(this),
            itemsNum = $(this).attr('data-appeared-items'),
            sliderNavigation = $(this).attr('data-navigation');
            
        if ( sliderNavigation == 'false' || sliderNavigation == '0' ) {
            var returnSliderNavigation = false
        }else {
            var returnSliderNavigation = true
        }
        if( itemsNum == 1) {
            var deskitemsNum = 1;
            var desksmallitemsNum = 1;
            var tabletitemsNum = 1;
        } 
        else if (itemsNum >= 2 && itemsNum < 4) {
            var deskitemsNum = itemsNum;
            var desksmallitemsNum = itemsNum - 1;
            var tabletitemsNum = itemsNum - 1;
        } 
        else if (itemsNum >= 4 && itemsNum < 8) {
            var deskitemsNum = itemsNum -1;
            var desksmallitemsNum = itemsNum - 2;
            var tabletitemsNum = itemsNum - 3;
        } 
        else {
            var deskitemsNum = itemsNum -3;
            var desksmallitemsNum = itemsNum - 6;
            var tabletitemsNum = itemsNum - 8;
        }
        owl.owlCarousel({
            slideSpeed : 300,
            stopOnHover: true,
            autoPlay: false,
            navigation : returnSliderNavigation,
            pagination: false,
            lazyLoad : true,
            items : itemsNum,
            itemsDesktop : [1000,deskitemsNum],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [900,desksmallitemsNum],
            itemsTablet: [600,tabletitemsNum],
            itemsMobile : false,
            transitionStyle : "goDown",
        });
    });
    
    
    
    ////------- Testimonials Carousel
    $(".fullwidth-projects-carousel").owlCarousel({
        navigation : false,
        pagination: false,
        slideSpeed : 400,
        stopOnHover: true,
        autoPlay: 3000,
        items : 5,
        itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3],
        itemsTablet: [600,2],
        itemsMobile : [479, 1]
    });
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Tabs
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show')
    })
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Css3 Transition
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $('*').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('data-animation')) {
            var $animationName = $(this).attr('data-animation'),
                $animationDelay = "delay-"+$(this).attr('data-animation-delay');
            $(this).appear(function() {
                $(this).addClass('animated').addClass($animationName);
                $(this).addClass('animated').addClass($animationDelay);
            });
        }
    });
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Pie Charts
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    var pieChartClass = 'pieChart',
        pieChartLoadedClass = 'pie-chart-loaded';
        
    function initPieCharts() {
        var chart = $('.' + pieChartClass);
        chart.each(function() {
            $(this).appear(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    chartBarColor = ($this.data('bar-color')) ? $this.data('bar-color') : "#F54F36",
                    chartBarWidth = ($this.data('bar-width')) ? ($this.data('bar-width')) : 150
                if( !$this.hasClass(pieChartLoadedClass) ) {
                    $this.easyPieChart({
                        animate: 2000,
                        size: chartBarWidth,
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        scaleColor: false,
                        trackColor: "#eee",
                        barColor: chartBarColor,
                    }).addClass(pieChartLoadedClass);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    initPieCharts();
    
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Animation Progress Bars
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $("[data-progress-animation]").each(function() {
        
        var $this = $(this);
        
        $this.appear(function() {
            
            var delay = ($this.attr("data-appear-animation-delay") ? $this.attr("data-appear-animation-delay") : 1);
            
            if(delay > 1) $this.css("animation-delay", delay + "ms");
            
            setTimeout(function() { $this.animate({width: $this.attr("data-progress-animation")}, 800);}, delay);

        }, {accX: 0, accY: -50});

    });
    
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Milestone Counter
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    jQuery('.milestone-block').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).appear(function() {
            var $endNum = parseInt(jQuery(this).find('.milestone-number').text());
            jQuery(this).find('.milestone-number').countTo({
                from: 0,
                to: $endNum,
                speed: 4000,
                refreshInterval: 60,
            });
        },{accX: 0, accY: 0});
    });
    
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Nivo Lightbox
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $('.lightbox').nivoLightbox({
        effect: 'fadeScale',
        keyboardNav: true,
        errorMessage: 'The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.'
    });
    
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Change Slider Nav Icons
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $('.touch-slider').find('.owl-prev').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>');
    $('.touch-slider').find('.owl-next').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
    $('.touch-carousel, .testimonials-carousel').find('.owl-prev').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>');
    $('.touch-carousel, .testimonials-carousel').find('.owl-next').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
    $('.read-more').append('<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>');
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Tooltips & Fit Vids & Parallax & Text Animations
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    $("body").fitVids();
    
    $('.itl-tooltip').tooltip();
    
    $('.bg-parallax').each(function() {
        $(this).parallax("30%", 0.2);
    });
    
    $('.tlt').textillate({
        loop: true,
        in: {
            effect: 'fadeInUp',
            delayScale: 2,
            delay: 50,
            sync: false,
            shuffle: false,
            reverse: true,
        },
        out: {
            effect: 'fadeOutUp',
            delayScale: 2,
            delay: 50,
            sync: false,
            shuffle: false,
            reverse: true,
        },
    });
    
    
    
    
    
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    /*  Sticky Header
    /*----------------------------------------------------*/
    
    (function() {
        
        var docElem = document.documentElement,
            didScroll = false,
            changeHeaderOn = 100;
            document.querySelector( 'header' );
            
        function init() {
            window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
                if( !didScroll ) {
                    didScroll = true;
                    setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
                }
            }, false );
        }
        
        function scrollPage() {
            var sy = scrollY();
            if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
                $('.top-bar').slideUp(300);
                $("header").addClass("fixed-header");
                $('.navbar-brand').css({ 'padding-top' : 19 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 19 + "px" });
                
                if (/iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 479 ){
                    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" })
                }else{
                    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 20 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 20 + "px" })
                    $('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : -7 + "px" });
                };
                
            }
            else {
                $('.top-bar').slideDown(300);
                $("header").removeClass("fixed-header");
                $('.navbar-brand').css({ 'padding-top' : 27 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 27 + "px" });
                
                if (/iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || $(window).width() < 479 ){
                    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" })
                }else{
                    $('.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').css({ 'padding-top' : 28 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 28 + "px" })
                    $('.search-side').css({ 'margin-top' : 0  + "px" });
                };
                
            }
            didScroll = false;
        }
        
        function scrollY() {
            return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
        }
        
        init();
        
        
        
    })();
});




/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/*  Portfolio Isotope
/*----------------------------------------------------*/

jQuery(window).on('load', function(){
    
    var $container = $('#portfolio');
    $container.isotope({
        layoutMode : 'masonry',
        filter: '*',
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false,
        }
    });

    $('.portfolio-filter ul a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false,
            }
        });
      return false;
    });

    var $optionSets = $('.portfolio-filter ul'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');
    $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) { return false; }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.portfolio-filter ul');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected'); 
    });
    
});
/* ----------------- End JS Document ----------------- */








// Styles Switcher JS
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);



$(document).ready(function(){
    
    // Styles Switcher
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.open-switcher').click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass('show-switcher')) {
                $('.switcher-box').css({'left': 0});
                $('.open-switcher').removeClass('show-switcher');
                $('.open-switcher').addClass('hide-switcher');
            }else if(jQuery(this).hasClass('hide-switcher')) {
                $('.switcher-box').css({'left': '-212px'});
                $('.open-switcher').removeClass('hide-switcher');
                $('.open-switcher').addClass('show-switcher');
            }
        });
    });
    
    //Top Bar Switcher
    $(".topbar-style").change(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == 1){
            $(".top-bar").removeClass("dark-bar"),
            $(".top-bar").removeClass("color-bar"),
            $(window).resize();
        } else if( $(this).val() == 2){
            $(".top-bar").removeClass("color-bar"),
            $(".top-bar").addClass("dark-bar"),
            $(window).resize();
        } else if( $(this).val() == 3){
            $(".top-bar").removeClass("dark-bar"),
            $(".top-bar").addClass("color-bar"),
            $(window).resize();
        }
    });
    
    //Layout Switcher
    $(".layout-style").change(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == 1){
            $("#container").removeClass("boxed-page"),
            $(window).resize();
        } else{
            $("#container").addClass("boxed-page"),
            $(window).resize();
        }
    });
    
    //Background Switcher
    $('.switcher-box .bg-list li a').click(function() {
        var current = $('.switcher-box select[id=layout-style]').find('option:selected').val();
        if(current == '2') {
            var bg = $(this).css("backgroundImage");
            $("body").css("backgroundImage",bg);
        } else {
            alert('Please select boxed layout');
        }
    });

});

/**
 * Slick Nav 
 */

$('.wpb-mobile-menu').slicknav({
  prependTo: '.navbar-header',
  parentTag: 'margo',
  allowParentLinks: true,
  duplicate: false,
  label: '',
  closedSymbol: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
  openedSymbol: '<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>',
});
```

Comment: Include the JQuery library?

Comment: Yes @MessEgberts I am loading it <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>frontdesign/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please check if the link to the JQuery is correct by viewing the page source and clicking on the link

Comment: Yes it is correct . I even added  this link <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>  . And script link is correct . It Could not fix

Comment: Try this: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: "appear is not a function". So it seems that the problem is with that function, not with jquery.  I don't think it's a plain jquery function, maybe you should include some plugin to add that functionality.

Comment: @MeesEgberts It didnt work .

Comment: @Eyescream I think appear is a Jquery function . I am still struggling with it to make  it work . I am loading Jquery Library before calling script .  I even tried to call it like on.appear .  Dont know what am i missing  ( I am not expert )

Comment: appear isn't a standard function in JQuery. You will need to add the [library](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)

Comment: @MeesEgberts yes  . I got those libraries in js  directory . I think you are correct , I am not including those . I will try to load all required libraries  and  post my comment

Answer (score 1):

.appear() **is not a standard** JQuery function, so you will need to also include the correct plugin/script after the JQuery lib file inclusion.